# Java servlet regex url

Tags: java, regex, url, servlets

I have a servlet. But instead of making that servlet listen to a static URL (e.g: `/testservlet`), I want it to listen to a dynamic url, or a URL with regex (e.g: `/testservlet[0-9]*`) which in this case will listen to a url **mysite.com/testservlet** followed by any numbers.
How do I do that?

Comment: what do you mean by listen to URL and why you need multiple urls for the same thing ?

Comment: @almasshaikh like each servlet/JSP is listening to a specific url params (eg "/test"), so every time mysite.com/test is called, the servlet's method service() is called

Comment: test is specific then why regex?

Comment: @almasshaikh instead of listening to /homepage, I want it to listen to a url with dynamic pars (like home[ANY_NUMBERS_HERE]page). Doesn't have to be regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your servlet class is: *victor.serlets.MyServlet*

In your application's web.xml, include the following:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>myTestServlet </servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>victor.serlets.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myTestServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/testservlet*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

As for the wildcard in the url-pattern tag, if you want to be more specific than "*" (i.e. anything), I am not certain what wildcards are supported.  I suggest you look at the [Oracle servlet docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html) for more info.  FWIW, I think the "*" wildcard will suffice for your app.